# How to make a responsive grid, using Ant Design?

Tags: css, responsive-design, antd

- I try to follow this [documentation](https://ant.design/components/grid/), but i can't make this work.
- I want to make the boxes break into one column for small screens, just like the follow examples.

[image]
Into
[image]

Do i have to use css insted of default components?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Use this code:

```
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import { Row, Col } from 'antd';

  <Row>
    <Col xs={24} xl={8}>
      One of three columns
    </Col>
    <Col xs={24} xl={8}>
      One of three columns
    </Col>
    <Col xs={24} xl={8}>
      One of three columns
    </Col>
  </Row>
```

or:

```
  <div className="ant-row">
    <div className="ant-col ant-col-xs-24 ant-col-xl-8">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div className="ant-col ant-col-xs-24 ant-col-xl-8">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div className="ant-col ant-col-xs-24 ant-col-xl-8">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Notice `xs={24}` is a shortcut for `xs={{ span: 24 }}`. So if you also want to change the order of the columns depending on screen ratio, you could do for instance something like `<Col xs={{ span: 24, order: 2 }} xl={{ span: 8, order: 1}}>`

Answer (score 2):

Scroll down to the last section of the Grid documentation you've posted:

```
<div nz-row>
  <div nz-col nzXs="2" nzSm="4" nzMd="6" nzLg="8" nzXl="10">Col</div>
  <div nz-col nzXs="20" nzSm="16" nzMd="12" nzLg="8" nzXl="4">Col</div>
  <div nz-col nzXs="2" nzSm="4" nzMd="6" nzLg="8" nzXl="10">Col</div>
</div>
```

Having in mind that the ant row can contain 24 cols and you mentioning Bootstrap in your post (this is regarding sizing: xs, sm, md, etc) - I believe you can adjust everything else.